# How to change root category via data patch in Magento 2?

Tags: category, stores

I've created 2 websites via config.php both using Default root category. Now im trying to change the root category to the ones I've created in Data Patch.

Im using the StoreManagerInterface to get the group and set a new RootCategoryId, but the GroupRepositoryInterface doesn't have the save() method. Any other ideas on how I could change the Root Category via code???

[image]

Comment: Use model class or resource model class

Comment: could you provide me an example?? I didn't understand what I should do exactly...